# How to format numbering of sections/subsections in titles and TOC in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, formatting, numbering, titles

I have some questions regarding formatting and numbering in Beamer.

I have changed the section numbers to double digits, which looks something like this:
01 Section 1
01.01 Subsection 1 of section 1
02 Section 2
02.01 Subsection 1 of section 2

I) How do I make the same changes for the numbering in the TOC?

II) How do I change the indentation of the titles in the TOC so that there it will align the numbers and the titles vertically, like this?:
01      Section 1
01.01   Subsection 1 of section 1
02      Section 2
02.01   Subsection 1 of section 2

III) Lastly, how do I suppress any numbering and formatting in a section-specific TOC? Specifically, the TOC for the second section in the minimal example should not have any numbering or formatting.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\two@digits{\@arabic\c@section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{%
\thesection.\two@digits{\@arabic\c@subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{%
\thesubsection.\two@digits{\@arabic\c@subsubsection}}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\insertsectionnumber~\insertsection\\%
\insertsectionnumber.\insertsubsectionnumber~\insertsubsection%
}
\begin{document}

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First of the first}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\subsection{Second of the first}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{Second section}
\frame{\tableofcontents[sections={2}]}

\subsection{First of the second}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\subsection{Second of the second}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I) How do I make the same changes for the numbering in the TOC?

You can redefine the `section in toc` and the `subsection in toc` templates

> III) Lastly, how do I suppress any numbering and formatting in a section-specific TOC? Specifically, the TOC for the second section in the minimal example should not have any numbering or formatting.

You can temporarily change how you defined the templates. As long as you do this within a group `{...}` it will only influence this one toc

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\two@digits{\@arabic\c@section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{%
\thesection.\two@digits{\@arabic\c@subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{%
\thesubsection.\two@digits{\@arabic\c@subsubsection}}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\insertsectionnumber~\insertsection\\%
\insertsectionnumber.\insertsubsectionnumber~\insertsubsection%
}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode%
  % prevents the period to be printed with the first/last section option
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
  \else
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
    \ifnum\inserttocsectionnumber<10
      0%
    \fi
    \inserttocsectionnumber.
  \fi\fi%
  \inserttocsection\par%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{
    \ifnum\inserttocsectionnumber<10
      0%
    \fi
    \inserttocsectionnumber.%
    \ifnum\inserttocsubsectionnumber<10
          0%
    \fi
    \inserttocsubsectionnumber
    \space\inserttocsubsection\par}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}


\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}
\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\section{First section}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\subsection{Second of the first}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

{
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \inserttocsection\par%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{
  \leavevmode
  \inserttocsubsection\par}

\makeatother
\section{Second section}
\frame{\tableofcontents[sections={2}]}
}
\subsection{First of the second}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}

\subsection{Second of the second}
\frame{\frametitle{x}}
\end{document}
```

[image]